# What is the correct term for diagnosis in automobiles?

Tags: vocabulary

I have to provide an English translation of my bachelor thesis' title and I couldn't find a term in the dictionary. At the moment I call it "Development of a car diagnosis application", but I am unsure if "car diagnosis" is the correct term. Maybe "vehicle diagnosis" or "automotive diagnosis" or ... ?

Comment: Could I please have the thesis in its original language?

Comment: Sure, but it's not written yet. :-) I need the title for registering my thesis at the faculty. I hope to have it done at the end of July.

Comment: Good luck! Hope everything goes smoothly for you.

Comment: Looking at Google Ngrams, "car diagnosis" is most common, followed by "automotive diagnosis" and then "vehicle diagnosis." But "car diagnosis" sounds too informal to me for a thesis title, so I'd suggest "automotive diagnosis."

Comment: I wish "mechanalysis" was acceptable, but it's not. Yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually the adjective *diagnostic* is used instead, for example 'vehicle diagnostic tool'.

Comment: so, does "Development of a vehicle diagnostic application" sound correct to you? :)

Comment: Yes, it sounds correct but you could use automotive instead of vehicle.  If you search academic papers they clearly use both and I can't tell if there is a different meaning.

Comment: "Development of an automotive diagnostic application". Sounds good to me, too. Thank you :)

Comment: Make sure to use automotive, as vehicle is ambiguous.